# starting to work with iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

i started following this tutorial i found via google.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925

However i got stuck on basically the first step where it said that the methods are deprecated, i changed them to the ones suggested by Xcode
the original code was

```
   [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

i changed it to

```
  [application registerForRemoteNotification:(UIRemoteNotificationType | UIRemoteNotificationType | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

but i keep getting the error message saying " expected expression "

i'm still at the first step here, this tutorial i'm following is for ios 6 
now i'm working on iOS 8 and i can't find any full tutorials on how to implement the push notifications to my application. can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the API wrongly.

First of all the Push Notification API has changed after iOS 8.0.

My answer will assume that you want to still supporting iOS 7.x and later

```
// Checks if the application responds to the API introduced in iOS 8.
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // iOS 8 Support
    // Note that you pass a object of type UIUserNotificationSettings as parameter instead of the enums only.
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];
} else {
    // Old API so use the same code from the tutorial
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: Still Gives me deprecated under this line of code ... 

 [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

thanks and i will keep working with the code you gave me along with the tutorial i am following and see if i can make it work all together :)

Comment: It will give that warn if you target is iOS 8 and up, then you don't need to worry about the if test, just the API right away. If you are using 7 and up then you need the if test.

Comment: ah okey i did that since as you said my app is targeting iOS 8+... and it is working like a charm ... thanks